# $F$ in $F(\mathbf{x},y)=G(y,H_{1}(\mathbf{x}),H_{2}(y,\mathbf{x}))$ is recursive?

Tags: logic, recursion

> Show that $F$ in $F(\mathbf{x},y)=G(y,H_{1}(\mathbf{x}),H_{2}(y,\mathbf{x}))$ is recursive by giving a description of $F$, where $G,H_{1},H_{2}$ are recursive.

I have to find a description of $F$ to show $F$ is recursive. I was thinking that $H_{1}$ is using redundant variables, where $H_{1}'(\mathbf{x}, y) = H_{1}(\mathbf{x})$, which is primitive recursive, and $H_{2}$ is using permutation of variables, where $H'_{2}(\mathbf{x},y)=H_{2}(y,\mathbf{x})$, which is also primitive recursive. But this is as far as I can go. How do I describe $F$?

Comment: So $H_1'$ and $H_2'$ are compositions of recursive functions, so recursive. Then show $f(\mathbf x,y) = y$ is (primative) recursive, and then $F$ is a composition of recursive functions, and thus recursive.

Comment: Oh I see, so I was actually describing F all along...interesting! Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: To be fair, I'm not familiar with 'give a description' as a technical term, but I would guess it just means to show at some fairly fine level of detail that $F$ can be formed from the formation rules for recursive functions.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen No worries! What do I do with the case $f(\mathbf{x},y)=y$? Is this a projection?

Comment: Yes, it is a projection.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen If it is a projection, isn't there an assumption that f is bijective primitive recursive function in order for the projection to be primitive recursive though? This is where I am confused...because I don't know what f is and so I cannot assume it is bijective or primitive recursive...

Comment: f *is* the projection function. The way I learned it, the projection functions are one of the basic pr functions from which the others are built. I'm not sure what this bijectivity requirement is referring to, but I don't think it's for this situation here.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I was thinking that the $y$ can be described using $I_{n+1,n+1}$, since $F$ is $(n+1)-ary$ and so the composition must preserve that arity.